# Bootstrap 4: Make right column scrollable, and use all available vertical space

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a simple two column Bootstrap 4 layout, as follows:

```
<main>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p>Left column</p>
                <p>Left column</p>
                <p>Left column</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <p>Right column ... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit....</p>
                <p>Right column ... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit....</p>
                <p>Right column ... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit....</p>
                <p>Right column ... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit....</p>
                <p>Right column ... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit....</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

How do I make the right column always end at the bottom of the screen, and be vertically scrollable?  In some cases, the right content will be only a few lines and will fit on a single screen.  Other times it will have dozens of paragraphs.

EDIT: A couple of additional points:

- In case it is not clear from the question itself, I want the right column to stretch to the bottom of the view port
- There are other elements above the `main`, including a `nav`, and their height may vary dynamically

Comment: put `bottom:0` for that div tag

Comment: use the property `overflow-y :scroll` to the `div` you want to scroll and to set it to bottom add two more styles to it as `position : absolute` and `bottom : 0`

Comment: Your question can't be answered properly without specifying more on the left content. Is it scrollable? Do you want the right-column to be fixed? What exactly sets the right-column's  height?

Comment: You can check my code, I tested it is working in google chrome

Answer (score 2):

You can add two css properties, so your right column will always stretch till the full length of your available page size. And when the data will try to go beyond you visible page space, a vertical scroll will appear.
Sample code:

```
<div class="col-md-9" style="height: 100vh; overflow-y: auto;">
```

Here is the working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/bootstrap-4-scroll-example-stackoverflow-0gdht

Comment: Check the added sandbox @KimPrince

Comment: Nothing from the question indicates the column should have viewport height. Maybe it should have the height set by the left column. Or by it's parent height. You can't answer without having that information because the answer would need to be different.

Comment: no height will be set, I think it is a full flow website fully scrolabble :) and he want place a floating div like advertisement banner

Comment: Whenever you need to make assumptions about the context you shouldn't answer. Ask for more details and answer when you have all the missing parts.

Comment: Hey Niks, that works provided there is no nav, and no other items above the main.

Comment: true, you can honestly down vote :) , I think the person who asked the question will slowly ask more questions :)

Comment: if left columns say has 100 paragraph how do you want the right column to size and fit ?

Comment: @KimPrince I have updated the sandbox with the fixed header, please check. Let me know if you want anything else. :)

Comment: @niks, I don't think it makes sense to have 100vh as the height when the nav bar takes up some of the vertical space.  The problem is exacerbated because the height of the nav bar can change in response to user clicks.

Comment: #KimPrince, not a big deal, Did you try changing the height of your nav? It won't break. I tested it by changing the height of your nav. Because 100vh is taking under the second row not the whole page, so your bottom condition will always full-fill with your nav dynamic height. Test as you want and let me know.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't entirely clear on what's expected on mobile. I'm assuming that you want the right column scrollable independent of the body so the nav remains at the top. I'm also assuming that you want the left sidebar to be scrollable as needed (independent of the body).

Therefore, I think you just need to make `position:absolute` responsive:

```
/* 768 is the medium breakpoint */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .position-md-absolute {
        position: absolute;
    }
}
```

and, the remainder is possible using Bootstrap utility classes:

```
  <body class="d-flex flex-column min-vh-100">
    <nav class="navbar">
        ...
    </nav>
    <main class="d-flex flex-column flex-fill">
        <div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column flex-fill">
            <div class="row flex-fill flex-column flex-md-row">
                <div class="col-md-3 overflow-auto">
                    <div class="position-md-absolute">
                        ..
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9 overflow-auto flex-fill">
                    <div class="position-md-absolute">
                        ..
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
  </body>
```

```css
/* 768 is the medium breakpoint */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .position-md-absolute {
        position: absolute;
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body class="d-flex flex-column min-vh-100">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-info">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Nav</a>
</nav>
<main class="d-flex flex-column flex-fill">
<div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column flex-fill">
    <div class="row flex-fill flex-column flex-md-row">
        <div class="col-md-3 overflow-auto">
            <div class="position-md-absolute">
                <p>Left column</p>
                <p>Left column</p>
                <p>Left column</p>
                <p>Left column</p>
                <p>Left column last</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 bg-info overflow-auto flex-fill">
            <div class="position-md-absolute">
            <p>Right column ... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit....</p>
            <p>Right column ... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit....</p>
            <p>Right column ... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit....</p>
            <p>Right column ... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit....</p>
            <p>Right column ... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit....</p>
            <p>Right column ... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit....</p>
            <p>Right column last... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit....</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</main>
</body>
```

Demo: https://codeply.com/p/93751rK5WQ

Answer (score -2):

If you want only one tag occupy full width without disturbing other tags, then you need to make that tag absolute

```
  <div class="col-md-9" style="position:absolute;bottom:0;right:0;top:0;overflow-y: auto">
```

so that other tags are not disturbed